# The Simpson's 1-3 (h / 3) method in Matlab

Tags: matlab, math, numeric, numerical-methods, numerical-integration

The C code that finds the following integral according to the Simpson's 1-3 (h / 3) method is given below. Fill in the blanks on the code appropriately.
I want to solve this question below in Matlab but i didn't do it. This is simple question but i can't do it. If someone will help me, i will be very happy.

[C code version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVGsD.jpg)

[C code version[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZmJo.jpg)

I tried this code block in Matlab:

```
% Ask for user input
% Lower bound (a)
a = input('What is your lower bound (a)?')
% Upper bound (b)
b = input('What is your upper bound (b)?')
% Subintervals
N = input('How many subintervals (N)?')
% Defining function
f = @(x,e) (e*x+sin(x))
% Finding h
h=(b-a)/N; 
% Finding the values of x for each interval
x=linspace(a,b,N);
% Calculating the integral
for i = 1:N-1
I(i)= (h/3)*(f(x(i))+(4*f((x(i)+x(i+1))/2))+f(x(i+1)));
end
answer1 = sum(I)
disp(I)
% adding f(b) to sum
val2=ff(length(xx));
sum=val1+val2+sum;% set sum
% set result
result=sum*h/3;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that MATLAB does not use the symbol `e` as Neperian Number (Euler's number). To produce Euler's number in MATLAB, you can use exponential function `exp(x)`,  `e = exp(1)`,

Therefore, First, correct your function definition:

```
F = @(x) exp(1).^x + sin(x)  % Always try to use Upper-Case letters for your variable/function name
```

Then, you can use the following snippet to calculate the Integral using Simpson's 1/3:

```
a = 0; b = 3; N = 1e4;

F = @(x) exp(1).^x + sin(x);

h = ((b-a)/2)/N; 
x = linspace(a,b,N);

I = 0;
for i = 1:N-1
    I = I + h/3*(F(x(i)) + 4*F((x(i)+x(i+1))/2) + F(x(i+1)));
end

disp(I)
% To compare your result:
Itz = trapz(x, F(x))
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Sir, you are a professional developer in matlab. I have a problem with another code block. If you have a free time, I want to show you. My friends and i could not coded this in Matlab. If possible, I would be glad if you could help with this. Not many people understand Matlab like you in here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65760255/huffman-and-average-length

Comment: Thank you dude, nice of you, it isn't true really, compared to many experts hear, I'm just a beginner, yeah sure I will try in an appropriate time

Comment: Sir, I think you are not a beginner, you are humble. Thank you very much again.